# Frontend e2e test - how to detect google map is initialised on selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-maps, e2e-testing, cucumberjs, webdriver-io-v4

I am doing frontend e2e testing using WebDriverIo(4.13.2) with CucumberJs.

And I am quite new to e2e testing.

My app uses Google map and there are map markers.

Basically, my e2e testing wants to do :

- Wait til Google map component initialised
- Search Google map marker DOM by `browser` object from WebDriverIo
- If the marker exist, pass the test

The problem is that Google map's initialisation takes time.

Sometimes it takes more than 30 seconds on Selenium.
So the second scenario fails. (Timeout)

I have tried `browser.pause(30000);`. So Selenium waits 30 seconds.

But it still fails depends how Google Map response quickly.
Moreover I don't think waiting 30 seconds is an ideal solution.

The below is the test code.

My scenario is :

```
...
Then I should see map
And I should see map marker
...
```

My step is :

```
Then('I should see map', async () => {
  const path = 'my-page map-component';

  myPage.mapComponent.waitForShadowDomElement(path);

  // Wait for 30 seconds
  browser.pause(30000);
});

Then('I should see map marker', async () => {
  const path = 'my-page ${page}'

  // Get marker img src
  const marker = await browser.getAttribute(`${path} #map img[src*="marker"] img`, 'src');

  assert.isTrue(marker.includes('marker-img.svg'));
});
```

I thought that `myPage.mapComponent.waitForShadowDomElement(path);` is not enough to wait Google map init because it waits just for the cover of map.

I also I have test like `browser.waitForVisible(MAP_PATH);`.

But no luck.

**How can I wait Google map completely being loaded on WebDriverIo?**

Thanks!!

*FYI,
In frontend, I am using Polymer component which WebDriverIo can't detect.*

*So I am using 3rd party library called [wdio-webcomponents](https://github.com/Morlack/wdio-webcomponents).*

Comment: Stack overflow warned me if I post this I might get some downvote. But I don't understand why. Can anybody explains me why this question got downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
The key was `waitForExist` method. ([document](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForExist.html))

```
Then('I should see map', async () => {
  const path = 'my-page map-component';

  // Wait for 30 seconds max
  await browser.waitForExist(`${path} #map`, 30000);
});
```

I have tested actually before. But I didn't use `await` that time. That's why it failed.